# C# - Reading a file UTF-8

Tags: c#, encoding

I have a windows form on .NET 4.6.1 and now, I am trying to read a JSON file in UTF-8 encoding, that I added to resources. I trying read it, but it trows an exception:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: at ....
JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: ﻿. Path '', line 0, position 0.
```

The way I am trying to read it is:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Resources.FileWithJSON));
```

I know, that file is reachable, because I tryed to change `Encoding.UTF8...` to `Encoding.ASCII` and it works, but with wrong symbols. Can somebody tell me, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: According to the error message, a dot is where it should not be.

Comment: It's difficult for me to properly answer this question, since I don't know what Resources.FileWithJSON contains. Is it possible, that Resources.FileWithJSON is already assuming some kind of encryption?

Comment: Inspect the string returned by `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Resources.FileWithJSON)` by itself, for example extracting it to its own variable with `var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Resources.FileWithJSON);`. If the `str` looks fine enough, it is not the UTF-8 decoding that is a problem.

Comment: @Hackrr show us a debugger output in debugger with evaluation of this Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Resources.FileWithJSON) and Resources.FileWithJSON. Seems you too much thinking about UTF-8, isn't it simpler just using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Resources.FileWithJSON)?

Comment: @ArturMustafin I can't show evaluation of it because it is the place, where it crash. And I need this encode, because it is requested by method that it converts to JSON.

Comment: We can agree that an exception of type `JsonReaderException` does not come from the call `Encoding.UTF8.GetString`, right? So clearly the call to `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` manages to return _something_, without exception. Therefore you ___can___ inspect the string it returns, and find out where it is wrong. When you know that, you can go back and look at the bytes in the UTF-8 file. This will make things more concrete.

Answer (score 0):

I don't how wrehe problem was, but it is solved... Originaly, file was named as **FileWithJSON.json** and I renamed it to **FileWithJSON.txt** and it works!
After that, I was able to remove `Encoding.UTF8...`.